# Gutenberg Block within Content

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I was wondering if it was possible to get a Gutenberg Block to display between/within the text of a Site/Post.
For example I mad a Gutenberg Block for all the new Wordpress Dashboard Icons, and was hoping to place it within the Text for practical usage.
If yes, how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should extend RichText tools, instead of registering new block.

Have a look at https://github.com/iseulde/advanced-rich-text-tools

And here is discussion in Gutenberg repo: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/10235